# Aligning elements in CSS relative to height

Tags: css, wordpress

[My Elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNu1g.jpg)

Hi,

I am learning to make templates in CSS in WordPress. I want to align elements so that they are equal in height.

I found the appropriate code in my template, but these blocks do not respond to any commands.

```
    `.cms-cmsservice-grid1 .grid-item-inner {
    background-color: #00257A !important;
    color:#fff !important;
    min-height: 355px;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    vertical-align:stretch !important;
     align-items: stretch;
     }`
```

The only thing I discovered is to manually enter the height to 355px, but then it looks nice only on the computer. On other devices where there are more lines (so the blocks are longer) they are still uneven.

I know you are experts. Tell me how I can align it so that the height adjusts to the longest block?

Comment: Take a look to flexbox or grid properties

Comment: I tried but I don't know how to do it. Please provide more details.

Comment: You can find a lot of tutorial if you search... but first of all, if you want an answer here, you have to be clear... for example read [mcve]

Comment: Add your HTML to the question

Answer (score 0):

## EQUAL HEIGHT + WIDTH COLUMNS

Add display:flex to the parent and flex:1 to the boxes

```css
.paddingBlock {
    padding: 20px 0;
}

.eqWrap {
    display: flex;
}

.eq {
    padding: 10px;
}

.eq:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background: yellow;
}

.eq:nth-of-type(even) {
    background: lightblue;
}

.equalHW {
    flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="paddingBlock">
  <h1>EQUAL HEIGHT + WIDTH COLUMNS</h1>
  <p>Add display:flex to the parent and flex:1 to the boxes</p>
  <div class="equalHWrap eqWrap">
    <div class="equalHW eq">boo <br> boo</div>
    <div class="equalHW eq">shoo</div>
    <div class="equalHW eq">clue</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't work with my block :/